# SQL Update a table column with a sequence of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I am required to create a copy of the data of one table within itself with a different range of foreign key in one of the columns. For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|TYPES         |ITEMS                 |SUBITEMS              |
|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| ID | VALUE   | ID | VALUE  | TYPEID | ID | VALUE  | ITEMID |
|----|---------|----|--------|--------|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | TYPE1   | 1  | ITEMA  | 1      | 1  | SUB1   | 1      |
| 2  | TYPE2   | 2  | ITEMB  | 1      | 2  | SUB2   | 2      |
|    |         | 3  | ITEMC  | 1      | 3  | SUB3   | 3      |
|    |         | 4  | ITEMD  | 2      |    |        |        |
|    |         | 5  | ITEME  | 2      |    |        |        |
|    |         | 6  | ITEMF  | 2      |    |        |        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here I have to copy from SUBITEMS and insert back but with ITEMIDs that have TYPEID as 2 resulting in the following example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|TYPES         |ITEMS                 |SUBITEMS              |
|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| ID | VALUE   | ID | VALUE  | TYPEID | ID | VALUE  | ITEMID |
|----|---------|----|--------|--------|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | TYPE1   | 1  | ITEMA  | 1      | 1  | SUB1   | 1      |
| 2  | TYPE2   | 2  | ITEMB  | 1      | 2  | SUB2   | 2      |
|    |         | 3  | ITEMC  | 1      | 3  | SUB3   | 3      |
|    |         | 4  | ITEMD  | 2      | 4  | SUB1   | 4      |
|    |         | 5  | ITEME  | 2      | 5  | SUB2   | 5      |
|    |         | 6  | ITEMF  | 2      | 6  | SUB3   | 6      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT 2: If the amount of rows differ in either of the tables (4 Items while 3 SubItems or 3 Items while 4 SubItems) then only those rows should be considered that are enough for a 1:1 relation between the two tables (3 result since that is the least count among either) as shown in the following example.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|TYPES         |ITEMS                 |SUBITEMS              |
|--------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| ID | VALUE   | ID | VALUE  | TYPEID | ID | VALUE  | ITEMID |
|----|---------|----|--------|--------|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | TYPE1   | 1  | ITEMA  | 1      | 1  | SUB1   | 1      |
| 2  | TYPE2   | 2  | ITEMB  | 1      | 2  | SUB2   | 2      |
|    |         | 3  | ITEMC  | 1      | 3  | SUB3   | 3      |
|    |         | 4  | ITEMD  | 2      | 4  | SUB1   | 4      |
|    |         | 5  | ITEME  | 2      | 5  | SUB2   | 5      |
|    |         | 6  | ITEMF  | 2      | 6  | SUB3   | 6      |
|    |         | 7  | ITEMG  | 2      |    |        |        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course the actual data isn't as simple and has many other types and items n subitems and the required IDs would be missing some sequence like 10001, 10008, 40042, etc with many other columns all defining what data is being copied and which IDs need to be thrown over them. It's just the matter of how each data row obtained should get mapped 1:1 to each ID obtained (assuming both as if in their own temp tables before the moment of this merger). Following is a sample of what I am able to do so far:

```
CREATE TABLE #SubItemsTemp (Value VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE #ItemIDsTemp (TypeID INT)

INSERT INTO #SubItemsTemp (Value)
SELECT
    SI.Value
FROM
    SubItems SI
    JOIN Items IT ON SI.ItemID = IT.ID
WHERE
    IT.TypeID = 1

INSERT INTO #ItemIDsTemp(Value)
SELECT IT.ID
FROM Items IT
WHERE IT.TypeID = 2

--What next?
```

EDIT 1: Forgot to mention the actual question line... How to insert them together into the SUBITEMS table such that the second example comes to fruition?

Footnote: This is a extreme simplification of the actual queries that have several joins to get to "TYPE"

Comment: Do you have to do inserts only for `TYPEID = 2 `? Whatif types have different number of items?

Comment: Yes it is for TYPEID = 2 at the moment and yes they have different number of rows for this case... 1065 SUBITEMS that need to be copied to of course 1065 ITEMS among 30294 ITEMS with TYPEID = 2

Comment: How they should be inserted? Show sample in the question

Comment: That is the actual problem, how to insert them together such that the second example comes to fruition. The second tabular representation is the expected end result. I should add this statement into the question i guess.

Comment: I know that is your expected output. Just add new row for `TypeId = 2` in `items` table. And show what will be expected result for such data

Comment: there will be none for a fourth row in Items table of TypeID = 2, only the number of rows that is equal among both are to be affected, since the data has to be 1:1. I'll update this scenario in the questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query. Query assumes that `ID` column in `SUBITEMS` table is identity and will work only with TypeId's 1 and 2

```
declare @TYPES table(ID int, VALUE varchar(100))
declare @ITEMS table(ID int, VALUE varchar(100), TYPEID int)
declare @SUBITEMS table(ID int identity(1,1), VALUE varchar(100), ITEMID int)

insert into @TYPES values (1, 'TYPE1'), (2, 'TYPE2')
insert into @ITEMS values (1, 'ITEMA', 1), (2, 'ITEMB', 1), (3, 'ITEMC', 1), (4, 'ITEMD', 2), (5, 'ITEME', 2), (6, 'ITEMF', 2), (7, 'ITEMG', 2)
insert into @SUBITEMS values ('SUB1', 1), ('SUB2', 2), ('SUB3', 3)

; with cte_1 as (
    select 
        s.VALUE, rn = row_number() over (order by i.ID)
    from 
        @ITEMS i
        join @SUBITEMS s on s.ITEMID = i.ID
    where
        i.TYPEID = 1
)
, cte_2 as (
    select
        ID, rn = row_number() over (order by ID)
    from
        @ITEMS
    where
        TYPEID = 2
)

insert into @SUBITEMS
select
    a.VALUE, b.ID
from
    cte_1 a
    join cte_2 b on a.rn = b.rn

select * from @SUBITEMS
```

Output

```
ID  Value   ItemId
------------------
1   SUB1    1
2   SUB2    2
3   SUB3    3
4   SUB1    4
5   SUB2    5
6   SUB3    6
```